# Migrating a string table (binary .res file) from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, embedded-resource, vb6-migration

I have to port an old VB6 program to VB.NET and stumbled across an old ".res" (Resource) file, which is stored in binary format. Using VS 2013, I can embed that file into my .NET project, and VS shows me that it contains simply a string table.

The problem is, I cannnot figure out how to bring those res file into a more modern text format, or how to load the strings directly from the res file. I linked file to my application es an embedded resource, but all my atttempts to use [VB6.LoadResString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.support.loadresstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the "Visual Basic Compatibility library" lead to an exception, showing the key was not found.

Furthermore, it seems VS does not allow me to copy/paste the string table into a text file, at least, not at a whole. Actually, it allows me to copy/paste one string after another, but as you can imagine, that is extremely cumbersome and error-prone. That is why I am looking for a better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You might better off skipping the Compatibility layer. At the same time it implements those old VB6 anachronisms like control arrays, it doesnt make use of better .NET approaches which refactoring allows.  Also notice that both methods for VB6.LoadResString are marked obsolete.

Comment: @Plutonix: yes, but that is not my problem. Even to access the strings from a different source (like a new resx file, an XML file or a plain text file), I first have to get them out of the .res file first. So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you use VB6 and loop from min to the max ID and write out the strings using LoadResString and trap for missing IDs?

Comment: Seems like there must be tools out there to extract a .RES file to data files.  Or write your own, since this is just the .RES file format most Microsoft tools like RC.EXE produce and the format is documented.

Comment: @KellyEthridge: yes, indeed, that will work in my case. I was actually focussing too much on solving the problem without doing any VB6 programming. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Bob77: that's what I was thinking, but Google did not help me finding such a tool. And if I had thousands of that files I would consider to write such a tool, but I guess there is some simpler way. I think I will go with KellyEthridge's proposal.

Comment: @KellyEthridge: if you make an answer from your comment, I will be happy to accept it if noone offers a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a functional VB6 Class for doing this at:

[ResDecomp Class Decompiles RES Files](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?802399-VB6-ResDecomp-Class-Decompiles-RES-Files)

Sample programs are included, one of them a sort of "viewer" and the other just extracts `RT_STRING` resource strings to an XML document.  You could easily change the latter to dump the string values to a text file, database, etc. instead.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I guess that one could be easily ported to VB.NET, if someone wants to.

Comment: It isn't very complicated so porting it to almost anything is possible.  Languages supporting unsigned numeric types and array type casting would be even easier than doing it in VB6.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the .res file to a simple VB6 program which loops from min to the max ID and write out the strings to a text file using `LoadResString` (error trap for missing IDs).

Comment: When I wrote "make an answer from your comment", I had "make a   **real** answer" in mind, not "copy - paste your question". But don't bother, I did this for you.